# Want to create a file, a directory created instead !

Tags: android, file-io

I'm using this code to create a file in the root of sdcard, however, i have a directory created instead of "fileDir+fileName" !

```
File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath(), fileDir+fileName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {

        Log.d("ERROR", "Create dir in sdcard failed");

        return;
    }
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
..............................
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because that's exactly what you're telling it to do with file.mkdirs()?

Answer (score 2):

file.mkdirs() creates directory and not the file [Ref: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29). This is the code which creates directory. you should use code something like this.

```
 String destination = currentdir + "test.txt"; 
        File fileCon = new File(destination); 
        if( ! fileCon.exists() ){ 
                fileCon.createNewFile(); 
            }
```

Alternatively try this,

```
     String destination = currentdir + "test.txt"; 


// Open output stream
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(destination);

            fOut.write("Test".getBytes());

            // Close output stream
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
```

Comment: maked this: String destination = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileDir+fileName; 
    File fileCon = new File(destination); 
    if( ! fileCon.exists() ){ 
            fileCon.createNewFile(); 
        }                          always the same problem

Comment: Try FileOutputStream as your old one,

// Open output stream
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + fname);

            fOut.write("Test".getBytes());

            // Close output stream
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

Comment: like this i'm not writing "Test" string inside the file ? :\

Comment: See if this example helps you anyway: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html

Answer (score 1):

file.mkdirs() is generating the directory structure in your if clause. You could test if you are able to write by file.canWrite(), I suppose.

Documentation is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Since you say, it is generating directories, it should return true, but the important part is not shown here:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting file.mkdirs() to create the directory for the file, then you need to tweak it slightly to file.getParentFile().mkdirs()

Of course, this should be wrapped in a try/catch clause, in case getParentFile() returns null

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello